# Unable to store updated array of dictionaries to userDefaults

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift, nsuserdefaults

**Edit, answer:**

Fairly simple, and should have spotted this earlier: `NSUserDefaults` still seems to require the Cocoa property list objects to work so the problem was using regular Swift `Ints` in the dictionary. They still need to be proper objects (obviously) and wrapped in `NSNumber`.

---

Pretty much what the headline says. 
I have an array of three dictionaries used for savedGamesData...

```
savedGames[savedGameSlot] = currentSavedGame
userDefaults.setObject(savedGames, forKey: "savedGames")
println("Saving savedGames: \(savedGames)")
userDefaults.synchronize()
println(userDefaults.dictionaryRepresentation())
```

savedGames is the array of dictionaries, currentSavedGame is the updated dictionary and userDefaults are the `.standardUserDefaults` The first `println`shows me that the data has been changed as I expected. Please note the *second* dictionary:

```
Saving savedGames: [
[score: 0, greatestTournamentReached: 1, goats: 0, match: 1, cash: 25, lastTournamentPlayed: 1, tournament: 1, gamesPlayed: 6, batSize: 1, greatestMatchReached: 2, bats: 2], 
[score: 0, greatestTournamentReached: 1, goats: 0, match: 2, cash: 11, lastTournamentPlayed: 1, tournament: 1, gamesPlayed: 2, batSize: 1, greatestMatchReached: 3, bats: 3], 
[score: 0, greatestTournamentReached: 1, goats: 0, match: 1, cash: 0, lastTournamentPlayed: 1, tournament: 1, gamesPlayed: 0, batSize: 1, greatestMatchReached: 1, bats: 3]]
```

However when I print the userDefaults *after* synchronizing the change has not been stored:

```
savedGames: (
    {
    batSize = 1;
    bats = 2;
    cash = 25;
    gamesPlayed = 6;
    goats = 0;
    greatestMatchReached = 2;
    greatestTournamentReached = 1;
    lastTournamentPlayed = 1;
    match = 1;
    score = 0;
    tournament = 1;
},
    { // This is the one that should have been changed
    batSize = 1;
    bats = 3;
    cash = 1;
    gamesPlayed = 1;
    goats = 0;
    greatestMatchReached = 1;
    greatestTournamentReached = 1;
    lastTournamentPlayed = 1;
    match = 1;
    score = 0;
    tournament = 1;
},
    {
    batSize = 1;
    bats = 3;
    cash = 0;
    gamesPlayed = 0;
    goats = 0;
    greatestMatchReached = 1;
    greatestTournamentReached = 1;
    lastTournamentPlayed = 1;
    match = 1;
    score = 0;
    tournament = 1;
}
```

Comment: What is the return value of `synchronize()`?

Comment: Good call(!), but it returns `true` so it *seems* to be working...

Comment: Don't use `NSUserDefaults` as a database or persistance for a data model, that is not what it is designed for. Instead create a Data Model class and save/restore with `NSArchiver`, use CoreData or another persistance store method. It will actually make developing the app easier.

Comment: @Zaph +1, That's good advice - but unfortunately doesn't clear up what's happening here.

Comment: Have you looked to see if the data is actually on disk after the save?